# How to dynamically create objects on the fly with click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create 2 rows of 6 rectangles (considered to be one object).

I also want to add a plus button, so that when the user clicks on either end, a new set of rectangles appear above or below the original ones. (depending on which plus button they click on)

So I am trying to achieve the following:

[image]
What I have tried/found so far:

```js
$(function () {
    $(".repeat").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $self = $(this);
        $self.before($self.prev('table').clone());
        //$self.remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="repeatable">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="userInput[]" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button class="repeat">Add Another</button>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The above example only works for forms. Does anyone know how I can go about making this work for what I want?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *The above example only works for forms.* ? This works without any form element, see http://jsfiddle.net/Yjtju/313/

Comment: @DelightedD0D sorry, what i meant was it only replicates the input form. I was wondering how I could get it to work for a series of rectangles, just like in my picture.

Comment: Im still not 100% on what you mean, your current code replicates the table, not the form, see here http://prntscr.com/civ6g9

Comment: Take out `'table'` from `$self.prev()`. Then it will work with any type of element, not just a table.

Comment: Put the rectangles in a `DIV` so you can clone the whole DIV.

Comment: @Barmar How would I be able to access a specific element? Suppose I cloned 6 times and I wanted to get the 3rd element. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Give them a class, and use `$(".classname").eq(2)` to get the third one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code to allow add to top, or add below.

I edited your event listener to check whether the button has a specific class. If so, either add above or below. It also listens to "body" click, because new DOM elements won't have event listeners attached:

```
$("body").on('click', ".repeat", function (e) { //other stuff here}
```

Also, changed your HTML so it wasn't dependent on "form", you could swap out the element types as long as the classes remain.

```js
$(function () {
    $("body").on('click', ".repeat", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $self = $(this);
        var $parent = $self.parent();
        if($self.hasClass("add-bottom")){
          $parent.after($parent.clone());
        } else {
          $parent.before($parent.clone());
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="repeatable">
      <button class="repeat add-top">Add above</button>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="userInput[]" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button class="repeat add-bottom">Add below</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```